# Tic Tac Toe Game in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I made this as a personal challenge. It seems to work fine as I can't find any bugs and am happy with how it runs, but I am interested in what I should do to make the code more professional.

*Note: This code was tested in Python 3.7.4.*

```
class TicTacToe:
    def __init__(self):
        self.p1 = '\U00002B55'
        self.p2 = '\U0000274C'
        self.draw = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
        self.counte = 0
        self.Print()
    def fillNumber(self,inputnumber):
        self.counte = self.counte + 1
        if self.counte % 2 == 0 :
            player = self.p2
        else :
            player = self.p1
        self.draw[inputnumber] = player
    def condition(self):
        if (self.draw[0] == self.draw[1] and self.draw[1] == self.draw[2]) :
            return self.draw[0]
        elif (self.draw[3] == self.draw[4] and self.draw[4] == self.draw[5]) :
            return self.draw[3] 
        elif (self.draw[6] == self.draw[7] and self.draw[7] == self.draw[8]) :
            return self.draw[6]
        elif (self.draw[0] == self.draw[3] and self.draw[3] == self.draw[6]) :
            return self.draw[0]
        elif (self.draw[1] == self.draw[4] and self.draw[4] == self.draw[7]) :
            return self.draw[1]
        elif (self.draw[2] == self.draw[5] and self.draw[5] == self.draw[8]) :
            return self.draw[2]
        elif (self.draw[0] == self.draw[4] and self.draw[4] == self.draw[8]) :
            return self.draw[0]
        elif (self.draw[6] == self.draw[4] and self.draw[4] == self.draw[2]) :
            return self.draw[6]
        else:
            return False
    def Print(self):
        for i in range(1,10) :
            print(self.draw[i-1],end=" ")
            if i % 3 == 0 :
                print()

class Game(TicTacToe):
    def start(self):
        try :
            inputnumber = int(input('Input number 0 to 8 \n'))
        except ValueError :
            self.start()
        if 0 <= inputnumber <= 8 :
            if (self.draw[inputnumber] == '\U00002B55') or (self.draw[inputnumber] == '\U0000274C') :
                print("This place is already paused")
                self.start()
            else :
                self.fillNumber(inputnumber)
        else :
            self.start()       
        self.Print()
        self.check()
    def check(self):
        if self.condition() == False :
            self.start()
        elif self.condition() == '\U00002B55' :
            print(self.condition()," Player one is winner")
        elif self.condition() == '\U0000274C' :
            print(self.condition()," player two is winner")

if __name__=="__main__":
    obj=Game()
    obj.start()
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you read pep8 (https://pep8.org/). I see you have violations. Understanding pep8 is a must if you want to be a pro Python developer. Better yet, use flake8 to automatically find pep8 violations in your code.

Second, using that many `elif` statements is always a red flag, especially when they seem to be doing the same thing. Can you somehow get rid of that duplication?

Next, put some blank lines between logical blocks of code to improve readability. In `Game.start` the try catch block is logically separate from the conditional following it, for example.

Next, give your variables meaningful names. For example, `game.start` is much better than `obj.start`. Also, avoid using shortened version of words, like `object` -> `obj` because it doesn't add much value and can decrease readability.

Finally, I'd like to see some tests. Not because I think your code has a bug but because I want to know how your code actually works. Because there's some logical reasoning in the nature of the problem, you can help the reader by documenting the algorithm you've implemented. Unit tests are perfect for this. They're fast, they target specific conditions one at a time, and document your code better than comments.
If you're wondering where to start when it comes to testing your code I suggest watching some videos on TDD in action. Kent Beck and Uncle Bob have some free videos showing how to do TDD step by step.

Comment: There's also a very good reason for using `obj` over `object`, because the long form shadows a builtin name. And perhaps some links to those video's would help.

Answer (score 3):

In no particular order:

1. Comments on what the variable names represent would be helpful, if for no other reason than to encourage more thought about your data model -- if it's hard to describe what each variable contains, maybe there's a way to store your data that's less confusing?
2. `p1` and `p2` look like static values, so I'd suggest making them class attributes rather than instance attributes (also it'd be good to have a comment in the code saying what these glyphs are).  Better yet, this could be its own class of `Enum` called `Player`!
3. The starting values in `draw` don't seem to have any significance, which makes the code harder to understand.  I get that you did this to make sure they'd never be equal when you're testing for win conditions, but I think it would be clearer to just have a single obvious "non-player" value like `None` and check for that when you do your comparisons.
4. `counte`(r?) isn't a very descriptive name; maybe `turns`, or `turn_counter` if you wanted to get verbose about it?
5. Instead of implementing a `Print()` method, implement `__repr__()` so that `print(your_object)` will do the right thing.
6. There's no reason to make `Game` a subclass of `TicTacToe` -- indeed, there's no reason for it to even be a class/object, since it doesn't have any state.  I'd just make a top-level function that creates a `TicTacToe` and runs the game.
7. If I understand your `condition` method correctly, it's checking for a winner?  I'd maybe call this `get_winner` and have it return an `Optional[Player]`.
8. The implementation of `condition` with all the `if elif` is very repetitive, but it's also hard to visually examine it and have confidence that it's checking all the right cases.  You could instead write a helper function that does the check for an arbitrary set of spaces and run that for all the winning sets, having all the winning sets lined up neatly so it's easy to visually validate them.

Here's a rewrite of just your `condition` method with some of the suggestions I've made, so you can get an idea of what this code might look like.

````
# Instead of self.p1 and self.p2 you can now say Player.ONE and Player.TWO,
# and these values will both type-check as "Player".
class Player(Enum):
    ONE = '\U00002B55'
    TWO = '\U0000274C'

...

    def get_winner(self) -> Optional[Player]:
        """Returns the winning player, or None if no winner yet."""

        def owns_all_spaces(spaces: List[int]) -> Optional[Player]:
            # Build a set of the owners of all the spaces.
            # If the set contains only one element, then either
            # one player owns all of them or they're all unclaimed.
            owners = set([self.board[space] for space in spaces])
            owner = owners.pop()
            if isinstance(owner, Player) and len(owners) == 0:
                return owner
            else:
                return None

        for in_a_row in [
            [0, 1, 2],  # 3 horizontal
            [3, 4, 5],
            [6, 7, 8],
            [0, 3, 6],  # 3 vertical
            [1, 4, 7],
            [2, 5, 8],
            [0, 4, 8],  # 2 diagonal
            [2, 4, 6],
        ]:
             winner = owns_all_spaces(in_a_row)
             if winner:
                 return winner
        return None
```
````

Comment: note that while it was tempting to try to implement a procedural method of checking for "3 in a row", I opted to restructure the way the code is written without changing the basic logic.  There's definitely more than one way to skin this cat.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, python has a style guide, PEP8. It's very useful for yourself and people reading your code if you follow this guide as it makes your code consistent, readable and idiomatic.

You have some typos and warnings in your code which show up immediately in my editor. It's worth looking at using an IDE to see these while you're writing. Personally I use Pycharm which has a free community edition.

When comparing to `0` or `False`, just use `not`. It is clearer and more idiomatic. e.g. `if not condition(): ...` or `if not i % 2: ...`.

Don't name things `Print()` or other python built-in names. Be more descriptive. e.g. `display_board()` or something similar.

Handling user input is often where a while loop is used to set an exit condition. It's usually recommended to only take a few incorrect answers, and to have better handling of invalid inputs. Take the following for example:

```py
max_attempts, input_attempts = 3, 0
input_number = None

while input_attempts < max_attempts:
    try:
        input_number = int(input('Please select a number between 0 and 8: '))
        if 0 <= input_number <= 8:
            # Input is valid, exit loop
            break
        else:
            print('Invalid input, input must be between 0 and 8')
            input_number = None
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input, input must be an integer')
        input_attempts += 1

if input_number is None:
    raise RuntimeError('No valid user input obtained.')
```

Here, I've clearly defined the maximum number of attempts, so there's no "magic number" 3 which may be confusing. I've handled different kinds of invalid input: not a string which can be cast to an int, or not a number between 0 and 8. I've also created an exit condition which is very clear and has a description for what is going on. This all may seem a little over the top for tic-tac-toe but it's good practice for the future.

@Sam-Stafford has some good suggestions for an alternative implementation of `condition()`. Checking against the list of winning positions is a good idea but I would not write it as an inner function, there's also no need to `return None` if no winner is found. Just check the board from turn 5 onwards for a winner.

It would be good to keep track of whose turn it is and exit when all of the board is filled in.

As for the class structure, personally I would have one class which keeps track of the board, it would contain win conditions and limits on size etc. Then a separate function which handles the game itself with user input etc. Inheritance shouldn't be necessary and I would discourage it in this case.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your code can have many improvements.

### Fixing the bugs

```
0 1 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8 
Input number 0 to 8 
asd
Input number 0 to 8 
asd
Input number 0 to 8 
0
⭕ 1 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8 
Input number 0 to 8 
1
⭕ ❌ 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8 
Input number 0 to 8 
2
⭕ ❌ ⭕ 
3 4 5 
6 7 8 
Input number 0 to 8 
3
⭕ ❌ ⭕ 
❌ 4 5 
6 7 8 
Input number 0 to 8 
4
⭕ ❌ ⭕ 
❌ ⭕ 5 
6 7 8 
Input number 0 to 8 
5
⭕ ❌ ⭕ 
❌ ⭕ ❌ 
6 7 8 
Input number 0 to 8 
6
⭕ ❌ ⭕ 
❌ ⭕ ❌ 
⭕ 7 8 
⭕  Player one is winner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 43, in start
    inputnumber = int(input('Input number 0 to 8 \n'))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'asd'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 66, in <module>
    obj.start()
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 45, in start
    self.start()
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 46, in start
    if 0 <= inputnumber <= 8 :
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'inputnumber' referenced before assignment
```

After the wrong input was given, the recursive statement was stored in stack and was run later.

`UnboundLocalError` occured because `inputnumber` was used inside `try` statement. To prevent that from happening, you can just add `inputnumber = None` before the `try` statement.

Even after that:

```
0 1 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8 
Input number 0 to 8 
asd
Input number 0 to 8 
0
⭕ 1 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8 
Input number 0 to 8 
3
⭕ 1 2 
❌ 4 5 
6 7 8 
Input number 0 to 8 
1
⭕ ⭕ 2 
❌ 4 5 
6 7 8 
Input number 0 to 8 
6
⭕ ⭕ 2 
❌ 4 5 
❌ 7 8 
Input number 0 to 8 
2
⭕ ⭕ ⭕ 
❌ 4 5 
❌ 7 8 
⭕  Player one is winner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 67, in <module>
    obj.start()
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 47, in start
    if 0 <= inputnumber <= 8 :
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

`TypeError` occurs because `inputnumber` was `None`, as a `ValueError` was caught while converting `inputnumber` to `int`. This moves on to the next line where it compares `inputnumber` (which is `None`) to `0` and `8`.

To prevent that, you must add `return` statement after `self.start()`

### Miscellaneous

- **Don't use elif statements unnecessarily**
- **Parentheses for `if` statements should be avoided**
  `if (self.draw[0] == self.draw[1] and self.draw[1] == self.draw[2]) :`
  should be replaced with
  `if self.draw[0] == self.draw[1] and self.draw[1] == self.draw[2]:`
- **In python, `if a == b and b == c` can be replaced with `if a == b == c`**
- **Use meaningful variable names**
  `p1` can be changed to `player1`, and `counte` can be changed to `counter`, `draw` could be `board`, etc.
- **`if somevalue == False` should be replaced with `if not somevalue`**

Here's the final code after some more small changes:

```py
X = '\U00002B55'
O = '\U0000274C'

class TicTacToe:
    def __init__(self):
        self.player1 = X
        self.player2 = O
        self.board = list(range(9))

        self.counter = 0
        self.Print()

    def fillNumber(self,inputnumber):
        self.counter += 1

        if self.counter % 2:
            player = self.player1
        else:
            player = self.player2

        self.board[inputnumber] = player

    def condition(self):
        # Rows
        if self.board[0] == self.board[1] == self.board[2]: return self.board[0]
        if self.board[3] == self.board[4] == self.board[5]: return self.board[3]
        if self.board[6] == self.board[7] == self.board[8]: return self.board[6]

        # Columns
        if self.board[0] == self.board[3] == self.board[6]: return self.board[0]
        if self.board[1] == self.board[4] == self.board[7]: return self.board[1]
        if self.board[2] == self.board[5] == self.board[8]: return self.board[2]

        # Diagonals
        if self.board[0] == self.board[4] == self.board[8]: return self.board[0]
        if self.board[6] == self.board[4] == self.board[2]: return self.board[6]

        return False

    def Print(self):
        for i in range(1, 10):
            print(self.board[i - 1], end=' ')

            if i % 3 == 0:
                print()

        print()

class Game(TicTacToe):
    def start(self):
        inputnumber = None

        try:
            inputnumber = int(input('Input number 0 to 8: '))

            if not 0 <= inputnumber <= 8:
                raise ValueError

        except ValueError:
            print('Please input a valid number')
            self.start()

            return

        if (self.board[inputnumber] == X) or (self.board[inputnumber] == O):
            print('This place is already occupied')
            self.start()

        else:
            self.fillNumber(inputnumber)

        self.Print()
        self.check()

    def check(self):
        winner = self.condition()

        if not winner:
            self.start()

        if winner == X: print(winner, ' Player one is winner')
        if winner == O: print(winner, ' Player two is winner')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = Game()
    obj.start()
```